# Release powerapp solution to new environment with devops

Tags: devops, powerapps, alm

I am interested in any information about or experiences with deploying PowerApps solutions to new environments within the same tenant.

In my solution I have a canvas-app and several flows between the app and sharepoint. I have used connection references to all connections (sharepoint, mail, etc.). On the devops side I have a build pipeline from my development environment, very much in line with Microsoft's recommendations for [ALM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/devops-build-tools). In addition, I have a release pipeline to publish the solution in another environment, e.g. a test environment. I can publish the release but when I access the solution in the new environment all flows have been turned off and all connections to sharepoint have been severed. When I inspect the flows it throws an error that it was unable to locate the connection Id. What strikes me as odd here is that the connection references that are visible in the new solution cannot be selected. However, what I can do is to add a new connection (from each flow), whereafter I can turn the flow back on and activate each of them in the canvas app.

What I am asking for here, is any documentation, guide, tutorial, help, etc.  to make this release a little more automatic, so I won't have to re-add connections for every single action from each of my flows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in luck  and you should check out the [latest PA community call](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-pnp-blog/power-apps-community-call-march-2021/ba-p/2228310). I think the last demo is the thing you are looking for (especially [from that moment I suppose](https://youtu.be/prWj2oGgAHY?t=3223)) and is now one of the targets in Power Platform.

If you are considering to introduce source control as well (like git), currently there is a cool experiment going on in the community in that direction which I think is quite promising and you may [check this article](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/ms-my/blog/source-code-files-for-canvas-apps/). But please consider this pack/unpack tool as an experiment and don't just remove the original .msapp files yet .

Comment: Thanks @adam that looks very promising indeed. I'll check this out and report back.

Comment: Okay, that wasn't quite what I was looking for but definitely interesting

Answer (score 0):

I think I have finally found a working solution. I'll document my steps here for other ALM hopefuls.
When pushing to the target environment for the first time I need to click on each of the connection references, click on solutions layers, [image: See pa_1])  use the breadcrumb path to go one step back [image: See pa_2]] and from here I can assign the correct connection. Subsequent deployments now work without any hassle.

Also, first time deployment, I have learned cannot activate workflows. However, future deployments can activate workflows by managing the setting the the Import Solution build tool